# error occurred when run cypress command : "command not found : cypress"

Tags: javascript, cypress, npx

I have installed cypress on my Mac computer and checked it by this command

```
npx cypress --version
```

And here is the result

```
Cypress package version: 9.7.0
Cypress binary version: 9.7.0
Electron version: 18.0.4
Bundled Node version: 16.13.2
```

But when I ran this command

```
cypress run --spec cypress/integration/2-advanced-examples/BDD/ecommerce.feature --headed --browser
```

and this command

```
 cypress open
```

it said to me this error  `command not found : cypress`

when I checked by this command

```
npx cypress run
```

it said to me that I had this error

```
Your pluginsFile is invalid: /Users/anhbui/Cypressautomation/cypress/plugins/index.js
```

Here is my index.js file

```
/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
module.exports = (on, config) => {
// `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
// `config` is the resolved Cypress config
on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

So, I do not know why i had this error ? Could you please help me to solve this error ? Thank you very much for your time.